# in php can not display uploaded files in apache root directory in ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-upload, apache2, document-root

in my web application user can upload images in their profile its all working , i want to store that image to /var/www/photos where my webapp is at /var/www/webapp so i am using this code

```
chmod($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/photos/".$p_name, 0777); (p_name is photo name)
```

i checked in /www/photos that photo has been saved and there is no permission issue but when i want to diplay that photo by

```
<img  src="{{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}}/photos/{{$value->photo}} >
```

it is not displaying photo , i checked in inspect element and path of that photo is

```
 <img itemprop="image" src="/var/www/sdesk/public/photos/book.jpg">
```

here is my apache/sites-enable/000-default file (.htaccess)

```
    <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
   </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride all
      Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

can anyone help me for this? thanx in advance friends..

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` gives the document root *on the server*, which is not accessible on the client. It’s even simpler, actually:

```
<img src="/photos/{{$value->photo}}">
```

Comment: but /photos/{{$value->photo}} gives me path like /var/www/webapp/photos/photo.jpg where my photo is saved in /www/photos/photo.jpg  ultimately i want to keep user photos in separate directory ...any suggestion plz?

Comment: @karanpujara: It shouldn’t; are you using a `<base>` tag?

Comment: @karanpujara: Did you change your `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/webapp`, then?

Comment: @karanpujara: No, I mean you shouldn’t have changed it. Are you absolutely sure it’s the path to the image that’s wrong?